# mobile app install ad creative create flow

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I'm just trying to create adcreative.
Why does not work..?
I can try this code request, but omething went wrong.

```
Array
    (
        [body] => Test body
        [image_hash] => dfae3f9ded3f42ad98aba419ed58e1ba
        [object_store_url] => https://itunes.apple.com/tr/app/test/id34563456
    )

https://graph.facebook.com/act_1234/adcreatives?access_token=ADFASDFADSF


error] => Array
    (
        [type] => Exception
        [message] => The Adcreative Create Failed for the following reason: Oops, something went wrong. Please try again later
        [code] => 1487390
    )
```

I do not know why. Can you help me please?

Comment: I know it's been a long time since this questions was posted, but today I ran in the same problem... did you found a solution?

Comment: same problem here .. found a solution ? :p